# Reference Pixels Per Unit

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple canvas (with **Render Mode** set to **Constant Pixel Size**) and with a sprite in it. I tried changing **Reference Pixels Per Unit** of the **Canvas Scaler** and **Pixels Per Unit** of the sprite, but with no result. The image has still the exact same size on canvas.

[image]

What is the purpose of **Reference Pixels Per Unit**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer on the Unity forums: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1309193/what-does-reference-pixels-per-unit-change-visuall.html:

> Just did an experiment. Sprite with pixels per unit set to 100 and canvas with reference per unit set to 200 will make the sprite shown twice larger than sprite with pixels per unit set to 100 and canvas with reference per unit set to 100. But in order to make the change happen visually, you need to click Set Native Size of the Image:
>
> [image: Showing "Set Native Size" button]

Apparently you will see the difference when you press "Set Native Size" on an Image.